# How to move folders into parent folder on Linux Ubutnu

Tags: linux, command-line, php

I have a folder structure with varying depths similar to the following.

```
parent/location/businessname/sublocation/hotelname
parent/location/businessname/hotelname
```

All of the lower most folders are Hotel Names and I'm trying to source these files in a PHP function. That aside, what I'm trying to do is to grab all of the lowest most folders and their contents into a single parent folder as below.

```
parent/hotelname
```

I'm on a Ubuntu machine and I'm new to command line but not totally ignorant to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try creating a symbolic link ln -s parent/location/businessname/sublocation/hotelname parent/location/businessnamen/hotelname hotelshortcut

Comment: Cant do that. Long story but symlink isn't possible, i need to ditch all other folders apart from the hotelname folder as the previous folders need to be exact names, but some of them aren't correct. Thanks anyway.

Comment: so bassicaly you want stretch the path?

Comment: What about File Explorer?  Does it have to be at the command line?  Unless you don't have access to X11..

Comment: Is the final directory always `hotelname/`? If so, you could use something like `find parent/ -type d -name hotelname -exec ln "{}/*" "{TargetDir}/" \;`. This would create hard links to each of the files in a single target directory without changing any of the files in the original structure. The target directory can be deleted or rebuilt at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the leaf-most folders are either in `businessname/` or `businessname/sublocation`, you could start with the nested folders first, then proceed to the hotels at the same level as `sublocation/`:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ rm -rf parent
$ mkdir -p parent/location/businessname/sublocation/hotelname1 \
           parent/location/businessname/hotelname2

$ for depth in 2 1; do
    find parent/location/businessname -mindepth $depth -type d -print0 \
      | while read -d '' dir; do
          echo "$dir"
          mv "$dir" parent/ \
            && rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty $(dirname "$dir")
        done
  done

$ find parent/
parent/
parent/hotelname2
parent/hotelname1
parent/location
```

This is a bit hacky in that it tries to remove the `sublocation/` directory repeatedly (for every hotel contained therein) until it is empty.

It also does not deal with name collisions -- it will move the first hotel with a given name and leave others in place.